# R - Using time to classify

Tags: r, time, time-series

a little help would not go too far.
I have to do a job based on the use of hours (24h) with 2 intervals (or more).
For example I use an interval from 08:30:00 to 18:30:00 and 18:31:00 to 08:29:00 (day+1)
I give illustrates what I did, a first view it works but on thousands of data, I realized that it was not optimal and that there was bad data classification...( 20:37 was in on "Work" instead of "Sleep")

Any methodological advice is welcome.

```
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")


#database
datetime <- seq(from =ymd_hms("2014-02-24 00:00:00"),to= ymd_hms("2014-03-20 23:59:59"), by="minute")
set.seed(123)
values <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 30), size = length(datetime), replace = TRUE)
df <- tibble(datetime, values)

#datastep 
 df <- df %>% mutate(H1    = hms(as.numeric(datetime)),
                    Hour   = hour(H1),
                    Minute = minute(H1) )
 
  setDT(df)[(H>= 8 & M>29) & (H<= 18 & M<31), statut:= "Work"] # range beetween 08h20 and 18h30
  test[(H<= 8 & M<30) | (H>= 18 & M>30), statut:= "Sleep"] # range 18h31 to 08h29 day+1
```

Comment: `(H>= 8 & M>29) & (H<= 18 & M<31)` is your problem, since half the times in that range of hours won't also be in the right "half" of the hour.  I'd suggest adding a variable with decimal time, e.g. hour + minute/60, then your ranges can be T >= 8.5 & T < 18.5

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
the problem in my case did not appear from there... probably a format problem somewhere.
On the other hand, I used another alternative similar to yours via a conversion of the hour into min.
the tests are conclusive and all the data have the right label.

`df$x_minutes ＜- hour(df$datetime) * 60 + minute(df$datetime) + second(df$datetime) / 60 `